# Determining the bs value for dd

Tags: linux, hard-drive, dd, advanced-format

I am using an external 1 TB WD hard drive with Advanced Format (4096 bytes sector size). What is the recommended value for the bs option in dd? Should I use dd bs=4096? And if I get this value "wrong" is there any data problem that could appear or is this option only in terms of speed?

Also I am securely wiping the hard drive, could I not fully wipe the drive if I am using the bs option?

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A block size between 4096 and 512K should suffice.
A **bs** smaller than than the physical sector would be horribly slow.
More than 128 times the sector size is also a waste since the ATAPI command set cannot handle such a large transfer.

> And if I get this value "wrong" is there any data problem that could appear or is this option only in terms of speed?

If it's too small (i.e. less than the logical sector size), then there could be issues.  Otherwise it's a speed optimization.

> Also I am securely wiping the hard drive, could I not fully wipe the drive if I am using the bs option?

As long as you use a reasonable value for **bs**, then there should be no issues.

Comment: "If it's too small (i.e. less than the logical sector size), then there could be issues" – Other than in terms of speed? Can you elaborate? What could they be?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski -- If you use the **seek** option or an oddball **count** with a less-than-sector-size **bs** (i.e. expect **dd** to perform a read before a write in order to perform partial sector operations), then **dd** will probably not do what you want.

Comment: Do you have any code or link to support this?